# Doing an animation in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am doing a java assignment for next Saturday.

Its going really well, however I'm struggling with one section.

Here I want to reveal a set of numbers in a String, one at a time.
I tried slowing down the loop with 'Thread.sleep(1000);'

however nothing is displaying until the thread is finished

the following is a section of the graphics class where the problem is occuring
is there something I'm missing?

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        setSize(550, 300);

        //this draws all the random numbers, revealing the ans to the user
        if (revealNum == 0)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            g.drawString(randomNumber, 20, 20); //draw String  ("the String", x, y)
        }
        //this reveals the numbers 1 by 1 to the user at the start of the game
        if (revealNum==1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < limit; x++)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawString(""+x, 20, 20); //draw String  ("the String", x, y)

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                    System.out.print("Error");
                }

                repaint();
            }

            //slow down the loop to show the user

        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270632/java-wait-for-thread-result-without-blocking-ui) question.

Answer (score 2):

Since yours is a GUI, calling Thread.sleep will put the entire app to sleep. Instead use a Swing Timer. Inside the Timer's ActionListener, add another letter to the displayed String, and then stop the Timer via the `stop()` method once the String is complete.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleAnimation extends JPanel {
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
   private JLabel displayLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

   public SimpleAnimation() {
      Action btnAction = new DoItBtnAction("Do It!", KeyEvent.VK_D);
      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(textField);
      topPanel.add(new JButton(btnAction));
      textField.addActionListener(btnAction);

      setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
      add(topPanel);
      add(displayLabel);
   }

   private class DoItBtnAction extends AbstractAction {
      private String textFieldText = "";
      public DoItBtnAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         displayLabel.setText("");
         setEnabled(false);
         textFieldText = textField.getText();
         new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            private int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (i >= textFieldText.length()) {
                  ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                  DoItBtnAction.this.setEnabled(true);
               } else {
                  displayLabel.setText(displayLabel.getText() + textFieldText.charAt(i));
                  i++;
               }
            }
         }).start();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleAnimation");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleAnimation());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Also,

- If yours is a Swing GUI, it would be easier to display your text in a JLabel or a JTextField rather than trying to paint it on the GUI.
- If this is Swing, don't override `paint(Graphics g)` but rather the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a JPanel or JComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Here is an example

```
JLabel l = ...;
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (l.getText().equals("1")) l.setText("2");
    else if (l.getText().equals("2)) l.setText("1"); 
  }
});
```